# jQuery lightbox have to popup on mouse over instead of click

Tags: jquery, lightbox, mouseover

I am using jQuery lightbox for show a gallery in my webpage it works fine but is I need the images popup when the mouse over on it I tried using below code but it does not works how to achieve it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).mouseover(function(){
    jQuery('#gallery a').lightBox();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This should work man...do u see any error in firebug...ur code is correct

Comment: @AmitPatil: nope no error found....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the javascript statement as **return this.unbind('click').click(_initialize);**

in **jquery.lightbox-0.x.js** (0.x means version of lightbox). Change this line as bellow

return this.unbind('mouseover').mouseover(_initialize);

Comment: Delete your browser cookies, Check your Scripting files and edit the proper file. Otherwise Try this. http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ download the new Lightbox. You can see jquery.lightbox-0.5.js file in JS folder. You just modify that file as i said. I have done same like that to post my answer to this question. For me it is working fine.